# google analytics reading the report - click event detail?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using google analytics and am using this code as an example to capture a click event.

```
ga('send', {
  'hitType': 'event',          // Required.
  'eventCategory': 'button',   // Required.
  'eventAction': 'click',      // Required.
  'eventLabel': 'nav buttons',
  'eventValue': 4
});
```

where do I find this data in the reporting?

what I am able to find is event catgory buton but I  cant find where this button was clicked with eventValue 4.

Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you misunderstand what "event value" means - this is to monetize non-ecommerce events. Which means event value is a metric, which in turn means that the values for multiple events will be added up.

So, the only case where you could possibly see the value "4" is when you isolate one single event. Else you will see a total (or average) for all events with the selected category/action/label (depending on the report).